# StaggeredGridLayout won't reapply on RecyclerView after the data is refreshed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that receive values from a API.
and the current configuration that apply is this:

```
recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
            addItemDecoration(GridItemDecoration(4, 2))
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            adapter = this@BusinessActivity.adapter
}
```

however when i refresh the data

```
refreshBusiness.setOnRefreshListener {
            refreshBusiness.isRefreshing = true
            skeleton.showSkeleton()
            businessViewModel.retrieveBusiness()
}
```

the whole view goes blank.

If i apply another LayoutManager such as (LinearLayoutManager or GridLayoutManager) instead of the StaggeredGrid, everything goes well.

and im assuming that the problem is related with the param that the Staggered won't receive and that is the context.

Anyone know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you refresh the data??

Comment: there's no need to call it, im using the ListAdapter that comes with DiffUtils. everytime i call submitList the changes apply without any problem. But the view only goes out with the StaggeredGridLayoutManager, if i do it with any other LayoutManager the redraw goes well.